# Jackson @JsonIgnoreProperties seems not to work all the time

Tags: spring, jpa, serialization, jackson

I mapped two entities to those following classes :

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = PropertyGenerator.class,
                  property  = "id")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id-generator", sequenceName = "seq_users")
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User extends IdentifiedById {

    @Include
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "email_address", unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    private String hash;

    @Setter
    private boolean admin;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = ALL
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("user")
    private Set<Cart> carts;

    {
        carts = new HashSet<>(0);
    }
}

@Getter
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "carts",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
                columnNames = {
                        "creation_time",
                        "user_id"
                }
        )
)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = PropertyGenerator.class,
                  property  = "id")
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "id-generator",
        sequenceName = "seq_carts"
)
@EqualsAndHashCode(
        callSuper = false
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
public class Cart extends IdentifiedById {


    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    private LocalDateTime creationTime;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = ALL)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "user_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"
    )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User user;


    @Exclude
    @JsonProperty("productStoreQuantities")
    @JsonSerialize(converter = AdditionConverter.class)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = ALL)
    private Set<Addition> additions;

    {
        additions = new HashSet<>(0);
    }
}
```

If I retrieve a user, its carts do not contain its reference, it is fine by me.
Now from a rest endpoint perspective I would like not to serialize users along with their carts if one requests multiple users like so :

```
**/api/users -> {"id":1, "emailAddress":"test@test.test", "admin": false}**

**/api/users/1 -> {"id":1, "emailAddress":"test@test.test", "admin": false, "carts": [...]}**
```

Thus, I created a wrapper class named Users containing a list of users annotated with @JsonValue and @JsonIgnoreProperties("carts") :

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Users implements Serializable, List<User> {

    @Delegate
    @JsonValue
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("carts")
    private final List<User> values;
}
```

I don't know why but carts keep being serialized, I heard that @JsonIgnoreProperties does not work on collections and arrays but it does in my first case.

Answer (score -1):

You should use JsonIgnoreProperties in a class level.
This is well explained in this post

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization